# Search in list item but show site only

Tags: office-365, search-results

Office 365

I have many project sites and each has a "info" list, this list has only 1 list item with a column "status" with values either "won" or "lost", so every project has a status defined in a list.

my task is to show "All won projects" and "all lost projects"

I have tried to configure search web part to filter on "status" filed which is available as managed property and return sites only but it does not show anything and I think it would not show because "status" filed is property of a list item it has nothing to do with the project site.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this requirement

1. Create a list content type and name it ProjectStatus
2. Add two site columns one to store the site url and another which stores the status
3. Now add this content type to the info list in all Project Sites
4. Now use a Content Query web part to display Content Type = ProjectStatus

You can further customise the XSLT to display only WON projects etc.

Comment: IIRC, Content Query WebPart is not available in SharePoint Online.

Comment: There would be thousands of projects, it is not possible for managers to create a project site and then make an entry in list.

Comment: You said there is an info list. I thought that is manually created and the entry is also manual.

Answer (score 0):

CQWP can be used in SharePoint Online